# I need to parse, modfiy and write back Java Source Files?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr

I want to create an object for each source file in my app. I need a mapping between Object and source file. I want my object to synchronize with its source file. Like ORM (Object Relation Mapping)

I need the tool parse java source file and then do works like get the Specific element and then modify that and update source file. or add a new element to the source file. Thanks.

Comment: besides being one of many **duplicates**, recommendations are **off-topic** as well.

Comment: I can't find any answer to my problem.

Comment: that does not change the fact that this is one of many **duplicates** and is **off-topic: recommendations** - *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: you should seriously read every topic under [Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: I need a simple tool.I don't want use antlr

Comment: so don't use it, but your question is **off-topic** regardless of what you want

Comment: Ok. I accept. sorry.

Comment: You need to use a tool that's complex enough for the task, which isn't simple.

Comment: @SaeedKayvanfar: You shouldn't be the sorry one.  The folks shutting you down are following a SO policy of "no recommendation" questions. That's silly IMHO because people want recommendations.  The consequence of this SO policy was the formation of a SO group called "Software Recommendations", just pushing these questions to another place and making a travesty of "no recommendation questions".  However, since they INSIST,  I'm always surprised that folks willing to tell you that you can't ask your question here, won't tell you politely that you *can* ask it at software recommendations.

Comment: @SaeedKayvanfar: Rats.  I didn't include the link to Software Recommendations: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: @IraBaxter Thanks.

Comment: @SaeedKayvanfar:  I note agreement with chrlis: tools that do that are not "simple" tools in terms of machinery.  They can be relatively simple to *use*.    (ANTLR isn't actually complex enough to do this well.) Check out the "duplicate" question for real answers.